# Laravel query failed using function query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to get sum of amount of all users group by month.But if I add sum then query not work.It return amount log as blank array But without sum query return all logs data as monthly.

My query

```
$reports = $user->whereHas('groups', function ($query) use($acceptedGroup) {
    $query->whereIn('groups.name',$acceptedGroup);
})->with(
    array(
        'amountLogs' => function($query) use($year){
            $query
            ->select(
                DB::raw('sum(amount) as total')
            )
                ->whereYear('created_at','=',  $year)
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("MONTH(created_at)",'user_id'))->get();
        })
);
```

If I remove

```
            ->select(
                DB::raw('sum(amount) as total')
            )
```

Then query works

Comment: What version of laravel are you on? Try `selectRaw` instead of `select`

Answer (score 2):

If you creating a specific select on a relationship in your query, you also need to include the foreign key to the related table (in your case, probably the *users* table)

```
->select(
   'user_id',
    DB::raw('sum(amount) as total')
)
```

This allows Eloquent to relate the records after loading from the database.